# MySQL query to return a column per date in date range?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-range

Let me explain what I've got and what I'm trying to achieve.
I have Table Look like this.

Let's say I have Table A: Booking

```
RoomNum     ArrivalDate    DepartureDate
101         2014-12-01     2014-12-03
102         2014-12-02     2014-12-03
103         2014-12-03     2014-12-04
101         2014-12-05     2014-12-06
```

the expected result should be something like the following :

```
RoomNum        Des-01    Des-02    Des-03    Des-04    Des-05    Des-06
101              1         1         1         0         1         1
102              0         1         1         0         0         0
103              0         1         1         0         1         1
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try something, then posted here?if you try search on google, many examples on this? just need to search??

Comment: Your expected results say 'Jan' but none of your dates are in January. In addition to that, not all your numbers match up. Room 103 has no dates on Dec 5 or 6.

Comment: Are you open to suggestions on DB schema changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have, while it may not be efficient or dynamic, is to use the SUM() function. Inside of there, you can include a case statement.

In this case, I wrote a case statement that checks if the current date is between the arrival and departure dates of a room.

```
SELECT roomnum,
  SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-12-01' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec-01',
  SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-12-02' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec-02',
  SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-12-03' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec-03',
  SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-12-04' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec-04',
  SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-12-05' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec-05',
  SUM(CASE WHEN '2014-12-06' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec-06'
FROM booking
GROUP BY roomnum;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bb6f/6).

Comment: no, it's shows different result. dec 2nd on Room Number 101 is 0

Comment: @PrimaSanjaya I'm sorry, I had misunderstood question. Please see the edit.